# Custom function does not work--throws error

Tags: r, function

```
test <-funtion(a,b){
  if(a=="apple"){
    if(b=="banana")
    x<-2
    return(x)
    if(b=="bin")
    x<-3
    return(x)
  }
  if(a=="a"){
  if(b=="banana")
    x<-4
  return(x)
  if(b=="bin")
    x<-5
  return(x)
  }
}
```

the error message as follows:

Warning message:
In if (a == "a") { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> }
> Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: What is the value of x if `a == "apple"` and `b == "b"'?

Comment: There's a typo `funtion` should be `function`

Comment: there is no value like that only options are apple, a, bin, banana.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your code. An `if` statement can only act on a single logical test. If `a` is a vector containing multiple values, then `a == "a"` will result in a logical *vector* with multiple values, and you get the warning error.

You have also misspelled "function" at the start and have not placed curly brackets appropriately around the `if` clauses.

You can simplify your function and also have it working on vectors by changing it to:

```r
test <-function(a,b) {
  
  2 * match(a, c("apple", "a")) + match(b, c("banana", "bin")) - 1
}
```

This allows

```r
test("apple", "banana")
#> [1] 2
test("apple", "bin")
#> [1] 3
test("a", "banana")
#> [1] 4
test("a", "bin")
#> [1] 5
```

and even vector inputs:

```r
test(a = c("apple", "apple", "a", "a"), b = c("banana", "bin", "banana", "bin"))
#> [1] 2 3 4 5
```